# Redirecting ".htaccess" with same folder name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

I have recently shifted my old site to a sub-folder called archives. All folder names are the same.

So, `/articles` has become `/archives/articles`
and `/editorials` has become `/archives/editorials`.

Now, this will not work since it will create a loop:

> RewriteRule ^articles(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/archives/articles$1 [R=301,L]

So, what should I do?

I have two Drupal installations, one at the root, and another one in the archives folder. This I have been able to manage with:

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/archives/"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /articles/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/archives/article/%1 [NC,NE,R,L]
```